# Menu on WPF Window title bar

Tags: wpf, menu, window, devexpress

How can a DevExpress menu be displayed on WPF window title bar, like below?

[image: Menu displayed on window title bar]

Right now, I have main menu docked to top of window, but I'd like to move it to window's title bar

```
<dxb:BarManager CreateStandardLayout="True">
    <dxb:BarManager.Bars>
        <dxb:Bar IsMainMenu="True" UseWholeRow="True">
              <dxb:Bar.DockInfo>
                   <dxb:BarDockInfo ContainerType="Top" />
              </dxb:Bar.DockInfo>
        </dxb:Bar>
    </dxb:BarManager.Bars>
</dxb:BarManager>
```

Comment: They are using a customized window.  You can do it also by modifying the Window template.  There are a few tricky bits like adding thumbs to the corners and edges, but overall it is a straight-forward Xaml and code-behind task.

Comment: Possible to share some code examples? I am using their custom Window so that approach is fine.

Comment: I put in some code for you yesterday.

Comment: Hmm, don't see any code...

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195870/wpf-bind-numeric-values-in-textboxes-to-change-relative-to-each-other/18197264#18197264

Comment: Well, how does that relate to this question about Title bar ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
              xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
 WindowStyle="None"             
              Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <dxb:BarManager CreateStandardLayout="True">
            <dxb:BarManager.Items>
                <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem1" Content="test"/>
                <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="barButtonItem2" Content="test2"/>
            </dxb:BarManager.Items>
            <dxb:BarManager.Bars>
                <dxb:Bar IsMainMenu="True" Caption="test1">
                    <dxb:Bar.DockInfo>
                        <dxb:BarDockInfo ContainerType="Top" />
                    </dxb:Bar.DockInfo>
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem1"/>
                    <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="barButtonItem2"/>
                </dxb:Bar>
            </dxb:BarManager.Bars>
        </dxb:BarManager>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I believe your code doesn't put the menu to Window's title bar but just docks it to the top just below the title bar.